# Как преобразовать найденный элемент в тип double?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Как преобразовать найденный элемент `IWebElement` в тип `double`?

Пример кода:

```
IWebElement SearchInput = Browser.FindElement(By.Id("betSize"));
double G = Convert.ToDouble(SearchInput);
```

Здесь мне ответили на вопрос, спасибо.
Но у меня потом возник новый вопрос. Как преобразовать число взятое из аргумента тега.

Например

```
<input name="" value="0.00000000" autocomplete="off" id="betSize" type="text">
```

и если попытаться преобразовать его таким образом

```
double G = Convert.ToDouble(SearchInput.Text);
```

то получится ошибка.

Решение

```
double number;
double.TryParse(SearchInput.Text, out number);
```

Comment: По поводу внесенной Вами правки - не думаю, что она уместна. Мой ответ раскрывает все нюансы, в том числе и преобразование и получения текста из элемента. В ответе была ошибка с типом данных, на которую мне указал @Grundy, которую я сразу исправил. В результате Вы привели решение - предложенное мной.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимо получить текст из найденного элемента, а затем преобразовывать значение. Попробуйте сделать так:

```
var searchInput = Browser.FindElement(By.Id("betSize")).Text;
double number;
if (Double.TryParse(searchInput, out number))
{ 
   // number - успешно преобразованное значение 
}
else
{
   // что-то пошло не так и преобразовать не удалось
}
```

Если у Вас элемент `betSize` имеет значение, которое можно преобразовать к типу `double`, то операция отработает успешно.

---

### Из документации [Selenium WebDriver — Selenium Documentation](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp), получение текстовых значений (C#):

> **Getting text values**
>  *People often wish to retrieve the innerText value contained within an element. This returns a single string value.
>   Note that this will only return the visible text displayed on the
>   page.*
>
> ```
> IWebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("elementID"));
> element.Text;
> ```

---

### Преобразование в тип `double`:

> [Double.TryParse - метод](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/994c0zb1(v=vs.110).aspx) - Преобразует строковое представление
>   числа в эквивалентное ему число двойной точности с плавающей запятой.
>   Возвращает значение, указывающее, успешно ли выполнено преобразование.

Не думаю, что будет лишним, проверить, успешно ли выполнено преобразование. Либо используйте [Convert.ToDouble - метод](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/zh1hkw6k(v=vs.110).aspx), как написано у Вас:

```
double G = Convert.ToDouble(searchInput);
```

Comment: разве _.Text_ вернет _IWebElement_?

Comment: @Grundy, да Вы правы, сейчас внесу правку, забыл. Вернет `string`